# Adding new element within a list inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

In a dictionary, I want to add a list of numbers for a given key.But I am unable to do it.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++){
   string input = Console.ReadLine();
   string[] inputList = input.Split(' ');
   count[Convert.ToInt32(inputList[0])]++;
   if(!map.ContainsKey(Convert.ToInt32(inputList[0]))){
     map.Add(Convert.ToInt32(inputList[0]),new List<string>());
     map_index.Add(Convert.ToInt32(inputList[0]),new List<int>());
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you getting exactly ? error , exception or an unexpected result?

Comment: Did you check to see if map_index has the key or not?

Comment: This makes no sense - add some more detail. What is `map`? What is `map_index`? What is `count`? etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is bit unclear. My understanding of your problem is as follows: You have a dictionary, a value of the dictionary is a list, and you have trouble adding an item to that list. Since you didn't explain your notation I'm using more general names, just to give you an idea what has to be done:

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> myDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
if (myDict.ContainsKey(myKey))
{
    myDict[myKey].Add(myVal);
}
else
{
    myDict[myKey] = new List<string> { myVal };
}
```

If the key is not in the dictionary you create an entry together with the list and initialize the list with the new value. If the key is there you just access the list (by using `myDict[myKey]`) and add the new value to the list. Since the list is always created for a new key you don't have to worry that it's not initialized when adding a value for an existing key.

Comment: Thanks mate, that helped a lot. Finally able to solve it. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be one the efficient Solution and much easier than if-else.

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> myDict = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
try
{
    myDict[myKey].Add(myVal);
}
catch
{
    myDict[myKey] = new List<string> { myVal };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a 'one-command-line' way to do this using [AddOrUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Concurrent_ConcurrentDictionary_2_AddOrUpdate__0__1_System_Func__0__1__1__) from [ConcurrentDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-5.0):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
 
...

var dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string[]>();
var itemToAdd = "item to add to key-list";

dictionary.AddOrUpdate(1, new[]{item1ToAdd}, (key, list) => list.Append(itemToAdd));

// If key 1 doesn't exist, creates it with a list containing itemToAdd as value
// If key 1 exists, adds item to already existent list (third parameter)
```